# Java: Access a variable which is inside an actionlistener

Tags: java, swing, constructor, actionlistener

I have trying for a while now to access a variable in my main class:

```
public class Results extends JFrame {
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
        System.out.println(doble);
     }}
```

which is inside an actionlistener, like this

```
public Results ()
{
 // Create a JPanel for the buttons DOUBLE AND NOT DOUBLE
    JPanel duplicate = new JPanel(
    new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    JButton doblebutton = new JButton("DOUBLE");
    doblebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    private int doble;
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                doble++;
                System.out.println("Doubles: " + doble);
                }
  });
}
```

I have tried like 5 ways to do it, but it doesn't seem possible. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving your declaration of **doble** outside of the constructor so that it becomes a field, like this:

```
public class Results extends JFrame {

    private int doble;

    public Results() {
        // Create a JPanel for the buttons DOUBLE AND NOT DOUBLE
        JPanel duplicate = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        JButton doblebutton = new JButton("DOUBLE");
        doblebutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                doble++;
                System.out.println("Doubles: " + doble);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Results results = new Results();
        System.out.println(results.doble);
    }

}
```

Some comments:

- Since **doble** is a non-static field, you need to access it using a concrete instance of Results. Look at the change I made to your main() method.
- Accessing a private field directly like this doesn't indicate very clean encapsulation and in fact generates compiler warnings.
- Using a non-word **doble** to avoid the compiler error on the reserved word **double** is probably not as nice as something more meaningful like **count**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I will accept your answer:) Thank you a lot. It seemed that I have misunderstood some things!:)

Answer (score 1):

currently `doble` is an **local variable** declared in your constructor, so its **scope** is only `confined to constructor`, declare it at `insatnce level` to access it elsewhere.

```
public class Results extends JFrame {
    private int doble;
      //cons code
   public static void main(String[] args) 
     {
        System.out.println(new Results().doble);
     }}
```

Comment: You are right also, but I have to accept the first, since it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The `main()` is static, the `doble` is instance variable. You have to instantiate, or make the variable static.